# How to make kills with Attack Jets on PC version of BF4?

Tags: battlefield-4

I often tried to play with attack jets in BF4 multiplayer but failed miserably.
To make clear which kind of planes I mean, the attack jets for each faction are: [A10](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/A-10_Thunderbolt_II#Battlefield_4) (US), [Frogfoot](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Su-25TM#Battlefield_4) (RU) and [Fantan](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Q-5_Fantan#Battlefield_4) (CN).

What makes it so difficult is that the initial secondary of those planes
are air-to-surface rockets that must lock on AND the player must hold the aim to the locked-on target after firing. The zoom of this weapon makes it even more unbearable. When I lower the thrust for having a little better chance for a successful rocket hit, I get killed by Anti-Air because I fly too slow for evasion. Sometimes the smoke/flares can save me from a Stinger/Igla but the cannons of the AA tanks tear me apart.

**My question: How do I have to maneuver my attack jet on the PC for playing successfully?**

The only guides I have found so far are for the consoles but I have no joystick or controller at my disposal, only mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Mouse and keyboard can be awesome for jets. I'm a decent heli pilot using the gamepad, but I don't hit anything if I fly jet with gamepad. Use ASWD for flying, but the mouse for micro-aim. If you want to unlock better weapons, try Air Superiority. There you get jet points for capturing, eventually unlocking better weapons.

Comment: @Sentry Thanks for the hint with Air Superiority but alsmost no server offers that (Europe). But apart from that, any tipps how can score with the intial weapons of the attack jets in Conquest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do figure 8 patterns always looping around the sides to come in across the map. On the attack run I am then headed into friendly territory (where there likely wont be any enemy AA). Usually the vehicles are positioned to protect them from the front line (like having a house between them and the opponent lines), which, with the attack run coming in from the side and behind, helps me line up laser guided hits. Most of the big vehicles can survive a hit, but if you find a damaged one, it will kill. Look for vehicles spotted on the minimap, since they likely are engaged already and may be damaged. Key thing, the laser guided is a definite *secondary*. The 30mm gau is your friend. Take out choppers, planes, stationary vehicles, and rack up the points until you unlock the other, better secondaries, like jdam or even the hydra rockets. 
If the figure 8 description isn't clear, I will edit.

Comment: I get it. Your route is always the shape of an 8, exploiting the whole extent of the map I guess. So the first available secondary weapon (http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Laser_Guided) of the attack jets is definitely trash and should NEVER be used? If you used them, how could you hold the lock (probably teaming up with a recon who laser paints the targets with PLD or SOFLAM)?

What about loopings? Aren't they at least useful for avoiding dog fights or getting rid of hostile aircraft at the rear?

Comment: Its not that they should NEVER be used, I just find the other weapons much more complimentary to the main gun. I can line up a run on a tank with the hydra rockets, then finish them off with the gun. Similar with the jdam. For maneuvering to lose aircraft search on YouTube for bf4 airplane turning. There's something about a best speed for turning. You have to manage your throttle and braking to get near a certain speed.  It sounds silly, but it will really help you out maneuver other jets, as long as they aren't already masters at it too.  I also switch to 3rd person in dogfights

Comment: Your hints are very extensive and sound awesome. Alas today I have no time for BF4 but I can't wait to try them out. I want to give others the chance too for providing a reply, thus I wait a bit for marking it as an answer.